# Run a stress test to see how healthy a SUSE web server is

Tags: google-chrome, dns, apache-http-server, php, suse

Experts hello and good day,

in the past few weeks i have had some issues on a server - with Wordpress and Limesurvey.  I also have opened a thread here. Now the site is up again 
and runs well. The limesurvey-page often has thrown a page like ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE Error (both on FireFox and on Chrome)

Since 24 h. the behaviour is better - the site is up again. see path: http://www.f-s-j.de/limesurvey/index.php/admin/index
limesurvey :: https://www.limesurvey.org/about-limesurvey/ version 3.20.02

it is installed in (between) a wordpress :: in other words: the limesurvey was installed under a folder inside my wordpress installation. 
Some limesurvey-experts say that i will get all kind of issues over the time. And that it has to do with the installation-structure:

- MyDomain.TLD/limesurvey/ (LimeSurvey)
- MyDomain.TLD/ (Wordpress)

hypothesis: LimeSurvey and Wordpress tell the server to rewrite URLs for the browser. In my setup Wordpress just tries to overrule certain settings of LimeSurvey. 
The Limesurvey-folks recommend that i would need to check every change and update manually the htaccess file (since it runs Apache).

Their final recommendation: To minimize work and trouble, I should install wordpress and limesurvey side by side.

we then need to redirect from MyDomain.TLD/ -> MyDomain.TLD/wordpress/, but then (after this step) I have clean folders and don't cause delays
and loops when it comes to URL accessing.  
This safe way of installation side by side includes a special procedure: to use /w/ for wordpress and /s/ for limesurvey will keep the URL short.

Again, it fails with an error: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE - after it worked very well for weeks.

what can I do now?

BTW, Wordpress on the server still runs well.

Note:  
OS: SUSE 
Kernel: 4.4
PHP Version 5.6.39
e.g., wordpress-basic-installation 
https://www.limesurvey.org/about-limesurvey/download
Sometimes I get the error: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE Error

Question: Can I perform a so called stress- or performance-Test to see how healthy the server is?  Is there a Performance-, Last- and Stress-Test for a Web server out there?

Comment: hi there - i run a suse-Server with kernel 4.4

Comment: Which release number do you use? Is it OpenSUSE or SUSE Enterprise? Please click [edit] and add that to your question.

Answer (score 0):

[stress](https://software.opensuse.org/package/stress) is available to run tests with, as is [stress-ng](https://software.opensuse.org/package/stress-ng) which has more features and is more comprehensive.  [Both are discussed here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/stress-test-linux-unix-server-with-stress-ng/).